# Armadillo create vector with colon range

Tags: c++, armadillo

I want to create a vector with the range (a:b) in c++ using `Armadillo` lib. 
It looks like this `matlab` code:

```
   D = 1:4

results:

   D =
      1    2    3    4
```

I tried to read [this document](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax), but I can't find the correct syntax in Armadillo. 
How can I create a `mat` or `vec` like this?

**Update**: thanks to @**timocov**, to be correct, the answer should be:

```
 vec v = linspace<vec>(start, end, end - start + 1) // +1 to get the end value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `linspace` function.

The ref on [doc](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#linspace)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I also updated my question with the correct answer.

Comment: sorry, can you help me with another problem about colon index? In `matlab` , I can access vector by range index like this: `A = D(3:6)`  Do you know similar syntax on Armadillo?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer already given, which is the right solution for generating sequences given the *number of elements*, if someone comes to this page looking for how to do so given the *space between elements* (i.e. the *interval*), the function for this task is called `arma::regspace(start, delta, end)`. Documentation [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#regspace).